# Extern "C" NULL Function Pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, extern

I've a problem with a libary which is written in C and my own code in C++, the issue seems to be that there is a function pointer which is declared as extern "C" but points to a C++ function (in my case the NULL pointer when I call the function from the libary) that is not declared extern "C".

Now in code:

```
function_from_lib( ... , (int (*)()) NULL);
```

Well here you can see that I pass the functionpointer to the function. The issue is that I need a function pointer which aswell points to NULL but the function to which "NULL" points (stupid) should be declared as `extern "C"`. Does anybody know how to solve such an issue or a workaround? I don't have a clue how the function looks inside but it needs a NULL functionpointer for my task.

So if I would have to pass another function like the following:

```
extern "C" int fkt()
{ 
return NULL;
}
```

it would have worked but I need a NULL function pointer.

EDIT:

Well this works:

```
extern "C" int fkt()
{ 
return NULL;
} 
...

function_from_lib( ... , fkt);
```

This wouldn't work:

```
int fkt()
{ 
return NULL;
} 
...

function_from_lib( ... , fkt);
```

And now I need to pass a NULL functionpointer

```
function_from_lib( ... , (int (*)()) NULL);
```

and it doesn't work because it isn't extern "C"

EDIT2 (ERROR UPDATE)

```
ERROR:
argument of type "I32(*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "I32(*)() C"
```

Comment: Please add a more complete code sample, what you have tried and isn't working

Comment: IIRC, `extern "C"` only prevents the function name from being mangled (C++ does that to allow e.g. function overloading). It wouldn't have any impact on a function pointer. What is the actual error that you get?

Comment: Now I hope it's a little bit more clear what I mean.

Comment: @Medo42, the C++ standard allows an environment to have different calling conventions for C and C++ functions. In such an environment, you simply can't cast a function pointer to another function pointer and expect it to work.

Comment: I found a pretty thorough discussion of the issue here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/wrkshp50/805-4956/bajdcjch/index.html. So yes, I was wrong, sorry :)

Lindydancer's answer looks good, but did you try this already? `function_from_lib( ... , (extern "C" int (*)()) NULL);`... it seems like it could work.

Comment: @Medo42, unfortunately, you can't write `extern "C"` like that, so I guess that this is a situation where you actually need a typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to use typedef:s. (I don't have access to a compiler that complains about your code, so I can't verify this). For example:

```
extern "C"
{
  typedef int (*my_fp_type)(void);
}

function_from_lib(... , (my_fp_type)0);
```